# Laravel 5 eloquent custom with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, methods, eloquent

i have in my eloquent model the record id of an api served data, i wold like to load this data using the with method to prevent multiple api request, is there any way to create a custom with method?

Answer (score 1):

**Eager Loading** can be accomplished buy adding a `with()` clause to any relationship query, for example:

```php
$books = App\Book::with('author')->get();
```

You can find more examples on the [Documentation Page](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

**Update**

You can also create a function in your **Eloquent Model** that will return a relationship with custom constraints or use the `protected $with` member on the **Eloquent Model**:

```
class Book extends Model {
    protected $with = ['author'];
    // ...
}
```